# rsync does not work correctly inside crontab

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, redhat-enterprise-linux, cron

I am trying to maintain a copy of a bunch of files from a remote server in my server, and to do that every 15 minutes I want to bring to my server the files that have changed in the last 15 minutes (since last pull)

The files may or may not be removed eventually from my backup server, so I don't want to rsync all the files because that would re-copy files that I have removed, every 15 minutes.

To achieve this I do an rsync every 15 minutes that fetches the files that have changed during the last 15 minutes, in the crontab in this fashion:

`*/15 * * * * rsync -av --files-from=<(ssh root@remote-server 'find /remote/directory -type f -name remote-server-files.* -mmin -15 -exec basename {} \;' ) root@remote-server://remote/directory /local/directory 2> /var/log/rsync_cron.log && echo "[$(date)] Remote files saved successfully" >> /var/log/rsync_cron.log`

When I run this command in the shell, it works just fine.

However, when the crontab runs it, it throws the following error:
`rsync: failed to open files-from file <(ssh root@remote-server find /remote/directory -type f -name remote-server-files.* -mmin -15  -exec basename {} \; ): No such file or directory
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1422) [client=3.0.6]`

So it looks like the crontab does not expand the inner command and execute it to get the list of the files.

Is there any awy to have crontab take the command normally?
I rather not create a script for a one-liner

Comment: the command in the shell gives this output:

receiving file list ... done
remote-server-files.000001

sent 163865 bytes  received 5819077 bytes  1087807.64 bytes/sec
total size is 553378247  speedup is 92.49

Comment: Create a `bash` script which you will just run from the `crontab`. It is not readable on one line and any maintenance would be a nightmare.

Comment: as I mentioned I rather not fill up the system with scripts for one liners. People tend to ask a lot more questions when you add a new script to a system

Comment: cron will run your command using `/bin/sh`.  So you need to either write portable shell commands or arrange for your command to be interpreted by bash.  Your choice.

Comment: *"People tend to ask a lot more questions when you add a new script to a system"* - so you're up to no good here?

Comment: _"so you're up to no good here?"_ Nope, I am solving a problem. But where I am when you add a new script, you need to document every single bit of it, provide a user guide, provide tests and incorporte to a support contract. 
A lot of work for a one-liner, I reckon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

The problem was that the crontab does not run on bash by default, it runs on sh.

I added this line at the top of the crontab and now it works fine:

SHELL=/bin/bash